# Race condition with Spring managed beans in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, spring

Consider a spring manged web service which defines an operation opA (class opA). A separate instance of the opA object will be created for every request for that operation.

```
Class opA{

@Autowired
B objB;

}

Class B{

C objC;
.
.
}

Class C{
.
.
.
}

<bean id="objB" class="blah.blah.B">
 <property name="objC">
   <bean class="blah.blah.C"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

NOTE: opA is also managed by spring

Here the object objB is Spring singleton scope with an inner bean objC. Now if two requests for opA arrive at the same time they both will have the same instance of objB right? causing a possible race condition on the sate of objC in objB. Am i correct? If not can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You have a single instance with state that's used all around your application so I'd say that you may have race conditions, but it depends on what is your `state` (is objB a Service and objC a Repository?) and on your implementation.

Comment: objB a simple Dao and objC is a container like "Map" which will hold values collected by Doa

Comment: Then yes, with no synchronization ad depending on your implementation, you could have different thread stepping on each other. As @Clockwork-Muse mentioned, Spring is quite irrelevant but it's more about Stateless vs Stateful. As a general rule you should try to make your objects stateless/immutable since they are thread-safe.